# Angular/RXJS - How to merge response of same HTTP Endpoint call triggered mutliple times based on different actions?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I implemented a infinite scroll and as part of this, I am triggering an API endpoint to get results in batches depending on the element position(used intersectionObserver). So in this case i would be hitting same API multiple times with different intervals. Sometime when scrolling fast i see the calls triggering very fast and view not rendering as expected. Is there a way in RXJS/Angular i can merge these responses OR wait for the first call to complete to trigger before initiating second call ?  OR any ideas/suggestions how can i deal with situation ?

```
        export class {
          @Output() eventscroll = new EventEmitter();
          @ViewChild('iscroll')
            iscroll: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

          @Component({
            selector: 'myinfinitescroll',
            template: `
    <div #iscroll></div>
              <ng-content></ng-content>

            `,

          });
          ngAfterViewInit() {
           this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
             this.iob.observe(this.iscroll.nativeElement);
          })
          }

          this.iob = new IntersectionObserver(this.handleScroll(),
                    { root: null, rootMargin: '0px',threshold: 0 });

          handleScroll([entry]){
            if (entry.isIntersecting && entry.intersectionRatio >= 0) {
                this.eventscroll.emit();   ///api call happens here, currently it is just a simple HTTP post call  
              }
          }

****Edit1****


myservicemethod(a, b, c): void {
    const reqdata = {
        p1 : a
        p2 : b
        p3 : c
    };
    const debounceWindow = 1000;
    this._callAPI$.pipe(
      concatMap((data): Observable<any> => this.myAPI.getData(reqdata)),
      bufferTime(debounceWindow),
      map((resp: Array<Array<any>>) => resp.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [...acc, ...item], []))
    ).subscribe((resp)=>{
      if (resp) {
        this.updateRecords();
      }
  })
  }
```

I am calling this.myservice.myservicemethod on component constructor and myservice._callAPI$.next($event) on component HTML

Comment: if you want to perform api calls in sequence, you can use 'concatMap' and also to handle scroll event, you should use 'fromEvent'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the solution isn't related to the code you post, in the sense that you should emit any way (you cannot debounce your emission or some data will be missing and the scroll will have some weird holes of missing data).

So, someone will be using your component like this:

```html
<myinfinitescroll (eventscroll)="_callAPI$.next($event)">
  <my-panel [data]="_data$ | async"></my-panel>
</myinfinitescroll>
```

So, let's suppose your data comes in chunks and each chunk contains an array of data and you want to buffer the responses for sometime before emits them in a single array, using you service method:

```js
grabSomeData(params: any): Observable<any[]>;
```

So, in the component typescript using you infinite scroll you'd have to do a few things:

1. Make the calls and receive the responses from the API in order
2. Buffer them for a while, let's say, 1 second.
3. Reemit all the received arrays of data as a single array

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma617710596433166?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=600)

```js
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {bufferTime, concatAll, concatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

_data$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

_callAPI$ = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
  this.scrollObservablesInit();
}

scrollObservablesInit() {
  // time window to buffer arriving data before reemits it
  const debounceWindow = 1000;

  this._callAPI$.pipe(
    // make the calls and receive the answers to the API
    concatMap((params) => this.myService.grabSomeData(params)),
    // buffer the arriving data for 1 second before reemit everything
    // in the buffer
    bufferTime(debounceWindow),
    // from above, now you get an array of arrays emitted 
    // by bufferWindow and we need to flatten it
    // obs.: there's an Array.prototype.flat operator
    //   on the recent versions on the ecma script, but
    //   let's not count on it here 
    map((data: Array<Array<any>>) => data
        .reduce((acc, item) => acc = [...acc, ...item], []))
  ).subscribe(this._data$)
}
```

Comment: thank you. Yes this is how my component will be used. This makes sense, i will try this solution and let you know the result.

Comment: Just FYI: if you replace `map` with `concatMap` operator, you won't need  `reduce`.

Comment: Hey, @AluanHaddad, could you show how to do that? You can edit my answer. Let's simplify the code.

Comment: Actually, it is simpler than I thought, the entire line `map((data) => data
        .reduce((acc,item) => acc = [...acc, ...item],[]))` just becomes `concatAll()` but when I was testing just now, I noticed that `bufferWindow` doesn't seem to exist in rxjs@^6. Did you mean `bufferTime` or am I missing something? I want to check that before editing

Comment: Absolutely: `bufferTime`

Comment: That's awesome!!

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I'm afraid it doesn't do what's asked in the question. It emits several arrays, not combined. I had understood that he wanted all the arrays combined in one single array to avoid successive fast rerenderings. Take a look at this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/concatalltryout?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) of what we got now.

Comment: Damn. Go back to what you had then, I can't look right now sorry

Comment: Switched it back. :D

Comment: @julianobrasil, I tried using as above, i am getting error 
Argument of type '(params: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>' 

I am not able get this work for my scenario. How can i access $event values in concatMap.  My eventemitter is emitting some values which i need to pass it my service method.

Comment: I've put together a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma617710596433166?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=600) for my supposed scenario. Take a look. Concerning your question, `params` should have all the `$event` values if your setup is like mine, with `(eventscroll)="_callAPI$.next($event)"`.

Comment: @julianobrasil My  service method is a bit different and i tried to apply this there. But after the last .subscribe still the resp is always coming empty array.   Updated my service in the question.

Comment: The parameters a, b and c that are passed to your service method... they are emitted by your infinite scroll component? Or they are declared in the component *using* the infinite scroll component? I'm asking this because in your question, the infinite stroll component emits `void`.

Comment: They are emitted by infinitescroll comp. I tried hardcoding those values for testing purpose but still didnt get any response.

Comment: If they are emitted by your infinitescroll comp, you should initialize the subject in the constructor as I did... It won't work with a calling to `myservicemethod` as you put in your question edit.

Comment: ok so you are saying i need to add this in comp constructor myservice._callAPI$.next($event) .

Comment: No... that one you put on the `(eventscroll)="_callAPI$.next($event)"` (like it's in my answer). You should put all the content of the `scrollObservablesInit()` in the constructor (also, like I did in my answer). It's an observable. It must be initialized just once and that's the magic of an observable.